# unable to boot 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I  have my hp probook 445 g1 ubuntu installed factory state. I was running out of boot space on my PC so I installed ubuntu-tweak to clean it.But it didn't worked. After that an error symbol is placed on top which says package has unmet dependencies. After that removed links from software update excluding the top four.

After when I restarted my PC it got stuck on purple screen.

What to do now?????? plz help me I have lot of saved in there

HOw to boot my pc now
I tried boot-repair but it didn't work 
here is the log file 
plzz help me www.paste.ubuntu.com/7825054/

Answer (score 0):

This happens when when your drivers are not compatible with your hardware.so u need to download the compatible ones.

1.First of all open the grub menu by clicking f6 or f7 when ur PC starts(depending on ur PC)and then open the OS in advanced-> recovery mode and then click on fail safe X mode and if it shows that you are low on graphics,cannot detect screen and devices then the problem will be mostly due to the driver.

2.Now depending on your hardware install the drivers from the internet whether its nvidia drivers or ATI etc.

3.Then go to the setting option->software and updates-> additional drivers->then selct anyone of the drivers and then click on apply changes and then restart your PC.

This will do your work if the problem is with the drivers.

for detailed description try this  [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)